# How would electromagnetic induction violate neither the conservation of energy or Newton's first law?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation

The basic premise of electromagnetic induction is that supposedly when you have a magnetic field moving, it generates an electromotive field perpendicularly, yeah? But if you had a hypothetical space where Newton's first law could be observed perfectly (no external forces at all), and you just had a magnet drifting on for infinity inside a conductive coil, how would that work? There would be no forces acting on the magnet, it would just remain in motion. The electromotive forces would just be coming out of no where then.

Comment: Have you never done the [magnet in a copper pipe experiment](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bang/handson/magneticcopper.shtml)? This shows nicely what happens in the situation you describe.

Comment: I'm more just wondering in terms of where the energy is coming from and going. I get that the magnet slows its decent, but that should require energy too. Where does that come from, and where does the energy going into the electromotive force come from?

Comment: The magnet induces currents in the pipe and the currents generate a magnetic field that exerts a force on the magnet.

Comment: Wow, that's a little bit meta. But again this experiment is not done in a closed system. The force of gravity is where some of this energy is coming from. If I have a magnet that isn't accelerating or decelerating, just floating through space, shouldn't there be no energy to go to the electromotive force?

Comment: If you did the experiment in free fall the magnet would slow asymptotically to a stop.

Comment: But where does the energy to slow it to a stop come from?

Comment: The motion of the magnet induces a current in the pipe/coil. That current creates a magnetic field that opposes the motion of the magnet. So kinetic energy of the magnet turns into the energy of the magnet field in the pipe. The current then decays due to the electrical resistance of the copper, and the energy ultimately ends up as heat.

Comment: Okay, that sort of make sense in a chicken and egg way. It is a bit bizarre to think that the kinetic energy of the magnet is being converted into electromotive and magnetic energy, which in is responsible for the force that satisfies Newton's 1st law taking the energy out of the magnet in the first place.

Comment: Re, "the magnet slows its decent, but that should require energy." IMO, that's the heart of your misunderstanding. Energy is not some kind of "fuel" that makes things move. Rather, it is something that you must _account_ for. If a magnet with mass $m$ moves with velocity $\vec{v}$ in some coordinate system, then we say that it has kinetic energy, $mv^2$ If something slows it down, then its kinetic energy becomes less. The law of Conservation of Energy says, that in order to explain the situation, you have to be able to account for the missing energy: You have to be able to say where it went.

Comment: You have to be very careful if you want to apply Newton's laws to a situation with magnetic fields.

Comment: @my2cts, that's a tantalizing comment. Maybe you could say more about what one must be careful _of_.

Answer (score 1):

When you move a magnet through a coil or even through space , a non conservative electric field is induced in space in a circular form. But, since energy is conserved in any case which can only be possible in this case if the motion of magnet is opposed so that the kinetic energy of moving magnet is converted into electrical energy and if you have a magnet just moving in a straight line with a constant velocity it will ultimately come to a stop, hope that helps, any other question you have regarding this, you can ask me.